# How do I pass the value of a prompt in a function as an argument for the same function when its called?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, prompt

I have a function playRound() that takes two parameters, playerSelection via prompt and computerSelection, and compares them. //basic rock paper scissors

a second function game() calls playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) to run the comparison for one execution.

I want the value of the prompt and computer to be saved and used for one execution in the loop, then prompt for new values from the user and computer for each of the following loops.

I know the prompt should be defined inside the playRound(), and so should the computerSelection but when I define it there and try to call them as arguments I get an error.

I have tried a few different implementations with the variables defined globally, inside playRound() and directly as arguments to playRound() with varying results that were inconsistent to the game.

Below is my latest implementation with variables defined globally, but this only runs once.

```
    const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
    let user = prompt('Your selection: ').toLowerCase();
    let computer = getComputerChoice();

function getComputerChoice() {
    
    let randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length);
    
    if (randomChoice === 2) {
        return choices[2];
    } else if (randomChoice === 1){
        return choices[1];
    } else {
        return choices[0];
    }
    
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection){

    //check for a tie
    if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        return('its a tie');
        
    } 
    
    //player choices rock
    if (playerSelection === choices[0]){
        if (computerSelection === choices[1]){
            return('You Lose! Paper beats rock.');
        } else if (computerSelection === choices[2]){
            return('You Win! Rock beats scissors.');
        }
    } 
    
    //player chooses paper
    if (playerSelection === choices[1]){
        if (computerSelection === choices[2]){
        return('You Lose! Scissors beats paper.');
        } else if (computerSelection === choices[0]){
            return('You Win! Paper beats rock.')
        }
    } 
    
    //player chooses scissors
    if (playerSelection === choices[2]){
        if (computerSelection === choices[0]){
            return('You Lose! Rock beats scissors.');
        } else if (computerSelection === choices[1]){
            return('You Win! Scissors beats paper.');
        }   
    } 
}


function game(){
    let playerScore = 0;
    let compScore = 0;


    
    while (playerScore < 4 || compScore < 4){
        const round = playRound( user, computer);

        if (round == 'its a tie'){
            return round;
        }

        if ( round.slice(0, 8) == 'You Win!'){
            ++playerScore;
            console.log('player score: ' + playerScore);
        } else if (round.slice(0, 9) == 'You Lose!'){ 
            ++compScore;
            console.log('compScore: ' + compScore);
        }

        if (playerScore == 3){
            return console.log('Player Wins!');
        } else if (compScore == 3){
            return console.log('Computer Wins!');
        }
    }

}

game();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: @MisterJojo Hi. thank you for this. I thought I explained what I tried in my question. I also made a smaller working sample of my issues with the logic for the game(). you can see that here in my GitHub https://github.com/SolomonM23/Odin-Rock-Paper-Scissors/blob/main/second.js    When I went to replicate it back in my main project, some other issues came up that I am having difficulty with.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a while loop to loop the rounds until the game is over.

```
const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
let user = prompt('Your selection: ').toLowerCase();
let computer = getComputerChoice();

while () {
    //code here
    ...
    if (playerScore == 3){
            return console.log('Player Wins!');
            break;
    } else if (compScore == 3){
            return console.log('Computer Wins!');
            break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively,

```
while (choices != NULL) {
    //code here
    ...
    if (playerScore == 3){
            return console.log('Player Wins!');
            choices = NULL;
    } else if (compScore == 3){
            return console.log('Computer Wins!');
            choices = NULL;
    }
}
```

I am unable to test this at the moment, but if this doesn't work perhaps looping the entire code (including user prompt) may work instead.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There have already been thousands of question/answers here about this game.
This will continue after you, and perhaps you too will be faced with the possibility of responding to it?
This one will probably end up being deleted, like all the others.
Simple unnecessary clutter question on StackOverFlow's server.

```js
const
  choices           = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
, getComputerChoice =()=> Math.floor( Math.random() * 3 )
, getPlayerChoice   =()=>
    {
    let index_on_Choices = null
      , user_Choice      = ''
      , badEntry         = ''
        ;
    while (true)
      {        
      user_Choice = prompt(`${badEntry} Your selection: ( rock | paper | scissors ) ? ${badEntry}`);

      if (user_Choice === null) 
        break;
  
      index_on_Choices = choices.indexOf(user_Choice.toLowerCase().trim());

      if (index_on_Choices >= 0) 
        break;

      badEntry = '!??! ';
      }
    return index_on_Choices
    }
  ;
gameLoop();

function gameLoop()
  {
  let 
    PlayerScore    = 0
  , ComputerScore  = 0
  , ComputerChoice = getComputerChoice()
  , PlayerChoice   = getPlayerChoice()
  , winOnPlayer    = -1
    ; 
  while (PlayerChoice !== null)
    {
    winOnPlayer = (PlayerChoice +1) % 3;  // % is Math modulo operator 
  
    console.log(`\nComputer choice was ${choices[ComputerChoice]}`);
  
    if (ComputerChoice === PlayerChoice)
      {
      console.log('Its a tie !');
      }     
    else if (ComputerChoice === winOnPlayer)
      {
      ++ComputerScore;
      console.log(`You Lose! ${choices[ComputerChoice]} beats ${choices[PlayerChoice]}`);          
      }
    else
      {
      ++PlayerScore;
      console.log(`You Win! ${choices[PlayerChoice]} beats ${choices[ComputerChoice]}`);          
      }
      
    console.log( `-- SCORE -- you: ${PlayerScore} -/- computer: ${ComputerScore}`);  

    ComputerChoice = getComputerChoice();
    PlayerChoice   = getPlayerChoice();
    }
  console.log('\nGame Over...');  
  }
```